# NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: Class 'Type' has no instance method '[]'. Receiver: Map<dynamic, dynamic> Tried calling: []("userId))

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: Class 'Type' has no instance method '[]'. Receiver: Map<dynamic, dynamic> Tried calling: ):
am trying to call the user from Map to the user profile UI
if there is a solution
//;..............................................................
//...............................................................

*NOTE: sorry for the chaos is made just to fill the post that was mostly code.

MY user_model:

```dart
  usermodel(
      {this.uid, this.email, this.Username,  this.photoUrl});

  // receving data from the server
  factory usermodel.fromMap(Map) {
    return usermodel(
      //the problem detctor is pointing here in this line of ===>( uid: Map['userId'],) <=========
      Username: Map['Username'],
      email: Map['email'],
      photoUrl: Map['photoUrl'],
    );
  }

  

MY Profile page where i used the model
the main problem:



buildprofileHeader() {
    return FutureBuilder(future:userRef.doc(widget.userProfile).get(),
    builder: (context,snapshot){
      if(!snapshot.hasData){
        return CircularProgress();
      }
      usermodel user=usermodel.fromMap(Map);
      return Padding(padding:EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            ch``ildren: <Widget>[
              CircleAvatar(
                radius: 40.0,
                backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
                backgroundImage: CachedNetworkImageProvider(user.photoUrl!),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
            child: Text(
              user.Username as String,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                fontSize:16.0,
              ),
            ),
          ),
       
        ],
      ),
      );
    },
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

`Map` is a type in dart, so it cannot be used as an argument name. It's common to call it `map` (all lowercase), or `json`. It should also be annotated with the type `Map<String, dynamic>`, to indicate that it is a json-like Map.

Your factory constructor code should then look something like this:

```
factory usermodel.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
  return usermodel(
    uid: map['userId'],
    Username: map['Username'],
    email: map['email'],
    photoUrl: map['photoUrl'],
  );
}
```

A side note, you should always capitalize typenames, so consider changing `class usermodel` to `class UserModel`.

Finally, later, when you call the constructor, you should pass in the data from your snapshot:

```
UserModel user = UserModel.fromMap(snapshot.data!.data());
```

Comment: i faced another problem that said snapshot should be defined